# How to obtain fine-grained control over split sizes when using a large number of splits?

Tags: vim-windows, split

Let's say I have ten splits as follows:

```
|0|1|2|3|4|
|5|6|7|8|9|
```

I now try to reduce the width of split 1 to be able to increase split 3 quite a bit (whoever wrote that particular file, used fairly long lines).

My problem is that when I attempt to change the size of split 1 with `Ctrl+w <` , the extra space goes to split 0, and if I attempt to correct that by changing the size of split 0, the only split I can get to change is split 1.
Similarly, changing the size of splits 2 or 3 only also affects split 4; changing split 4 only affects split 3. 
So in short, I fail in my attempts to move the divider located between splits 1 and 2.

How do I get around this? I have not yet attempted to get the mouse involved (would like to try to avoid that, if possible).

Comment: So to be more precise: I'm trying to resize existing windows/splits without having to close a bunch of windows and reopen them. Which perhaps would work, if I managed to perform the required `:sp` and `:vs` in the right order.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. My horizontal resize operations always move the divider to the right of the current window, regardless of what order I opened them in (except when that window is rightmost, obviously). Can you add a sequence of split operations that always results in a window layout that behaves like this for you, or is the issue more unpredictable than that?

Answer (score 1):

Prefix a number before the split command to reduce it to a desired number of rows or columns: e.g., `:10sp` or `:20vsp`

See also: `:help sp`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that would help. I am after all not trying to open new windows, but resize existing windows.

Comment: Sure, I could make an attempt to close existing windows and reopening them in the right order (there appears to be a difference if I do `:sp` before `:vs` versus the other order), whatever that "right order" actually is. (Oops, shouldn't have hit enter while typing here. Sorry for two comments instead of one)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understod you, all you have to do is:

1. Go to split 1 `Ctrl+w 10<`
2. Go to split 2 `Ctrl+w 10<`

Split 1 is now 10 columns smaller, and split 3 is 10 columns bigger.

What you do is he following:

Starting:

`| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |`

Decrease the width of split 1:

`| 0 | 1|  2 | 3 | 4 |`

The width you have taken from split 1 is now in split 2.
So to restore split 2 to the original size, and to pass the extra width further to split 3, you have to decrease the width of split 2 by the same amount:

`| 0 | 1| 2 |  3 | 4 |`

Since you have writen that `Ctrl+w <` decreases split 0, it is possible, that you have to go the other way arround, and use `Ctrl+w 10>`on split 4

Comment: That result is not guaranteed. Doing `Ctrl+w 10<` on split 2 is not guaranteed to change the size of spit 3 - indeed, my problem was that when doing that, it would resize split 1 instead, going back to the initial configuration and leave split 3 alone.
It seemed to have something to do with the order in which I had opened the splits - some appeared to be grouped together, such that all size changes took place within the group.

Comment: Yeah it has something to do with the order. But as I said, try to do `Ctrl+w 10>` on split 4.